# Obtaining Distribution of $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ using density function

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus, order-statistics

I am given $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} U(\alpha, \beta)$, and asked to find joint distribution of order statistics- $X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}$. Though I know there exists a much simpler solution, but I wanted to try integrating the joint density instead.

The equation looked as follows-
\begin{align*}
F_{X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}} (x,y)  &= \frac{n(n-1)}{(\beta-\alpha)^n}\int_{\alpha}^y \int_{\alpha}^x (v-u)^{n-2} du \cdot dv
\\ &= \frac{(y-\alpha)^n - (y-x)^n + (\alpha - x)^n}{(\beta-\alpha)^n}
\end{align*}

The equation is correct except for the last $(\alpha-x)^n$ term. Since my joint density is correct, I inferred the mistake must be in my integral. I have tried changing the limits and reversing the order of integrals but nothing seems to work. I would be grateful if anyone could tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper limit on your inner integral should be $\ \min(x,v)\ $  because the density isn't always $\ \frac{n(n-1)(v-u)^{n-1}}{(\beta-\alpha)^n}\ $. When $\ u>v\ $, it vanishes.

Comment: So I need to break this integral down into two cases, $x<v$ and $x \geq v$? In that case when, $x<v$, the problem in my integral would remain?

Comment: No. You need to split the outer integral into two pieces, from $\ \alpha $ to $\ x\ $, when $ v\le x\ $ and the upper limit of the inner integral will then be $\ v\ $, and from $\ x\ $ to $\ y\ $ when $\ x\le v\le y\ $ and the upper limit of the inner integral will be $\ x\ $.  You only need to do this for $\ x < y\ $, because if $\ y\le x\ $, then $\ F_{X_{(1)},X_{(n)}}(x,y)=F_{X_{(n)}}(y)\ $.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what you said, but I got it now and it worked. Thanks a lot!